# Crashes using Bluetooth Android studio/java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, crash

When I am using in my app and it does something it wasn't supposed to like try to connect to paired but not connected Bluetooth device. The app crashes, I want to see if there is a way to catch the errors and stop the app from crashing.
I'm using

```
try {

    socket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("ConnectFail", "Socket.connect() Failed", e);
    //e.printStackTrace();

    break;
}
```

but it still crashes.

Comment: Check the error log for more info. If you are can calling `socket.connect()` on main Thread this might cause crash

Comment: `I want to see if there is a way to catch the errors and stop the app from crashing. ` Simple. Find out whch exceptions that let your app crash you do not catch. Then catch these eceptions too. The logcat is your friend.

Comment: How do I do that can you give me an example. Because most of the crash are when I try socket.connect()

Comment: You need to share the error log to see where your code is crashing

Comment: Sometimes it catch the error and doesn't crash other time it just don't and crash. And also when I try to choose which Bluetooth to connect to (I have drop down menu) the app just freeze for couple of seconds then it or connect or crash.